How to create two frames (top and bottom) that have the same height, using Tkinter?
In Tkinter Python, I want to create two frames and place one on top of the other, and then insert a matplotlib plot inside each of these two frames. That, I managed to do. The problem is that, when created, these two frames always seem to have different heights (the bottom one is always smaller than the top one).
My goal is to get the two frames to have the same height.
Here's a simplified version of the code that produces the said undesirable result :
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Root
root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')

# Upper frame 
canv = tk.Frame(root)
canv.pack()

plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = plt.cycler(color=["#4C2A85", "#BE96FF", "#957DAD", "#5E366E", "#A98CCC"])
plt.style.use('ggplot')

L = [i for i in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l = ax.fill_between(L, L)
ax.set_title("Upper plot")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, canv)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

# Lower frame 
canv2 = tk.Frame(root)
canv2.pack()

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
l2 = ax2.fill_between(L, L)
ax2.set_title("Lower plot")
    
canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, canv2)
canvas2.draw()
canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack()

root.mainloop

Thanks to anyone willing to help.

did you tried to use height= in canvas? Did you try to write plots to file to see if they are the same size? Maybe you have to correct heights of your plots.

if you get widget = canvas.get_tk_widget() then you can set height manually widget['height'] = 300 and later widget.pack() - and the same for canvas2. But it will not resize when you resize window. It would need to add function which update height when you resize window. I didn't check if would work grid() with rowconfigure(..., weight=1)

other idea: one FigureCanvasTkAgg and use one subplots() to create two ax1, ax2 to make two plots on the same canvas.

Different idea: create one FigureCanvasTkAgg but two axis
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

and matplotlib will control size.
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

root = tk.Tk()
#root.state('zoomed')

plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = plt.cycler(color=["#4C2A85", "#BE96FF", "#957DAD", "#5E366E", "#A98CCC"])
plt.style.use('ggplot')

L = [i for i in range(10)]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)

l1 = ax1.fill_between(L, L)
ax1.set_title("Upper plot")

l2 = ax2.fill_between(L, L)
ax2.set_title("Lower plot")

fig.tight_layout()  # suggestion from @Zakaria comment

root.mainloop()


This works, thanks. I had to add fig.tight_layout() right before the last line of code in order to prevent the two subplots from overlapping.

@Zakaria thank you - I added your suggestion to code.

If you use grid() instead of pack() to put both Frame then you can use root.rowconfigure(.., weight=1) to set how it will split window's height into rows.
And it will automatically resize Frame's height when you resize window.
root = tk.Tk()

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)      # `weight/sum_of_all_row_weights` = 1/2 height
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)      # `weight/sum_of_all_row_weights` = 1/2 height
#root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # `weight/sum_of_all_column_weights` = 1/1 width

canv = tk.Frame(root)
canv.grid(column=0, row=0)

#... code ...

canv2 = tk.Frame(root)
canv2.grid(column=0, row=1)

#... code ...



I tested on Linux without root.state('zoomed')
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Root
root = tk.Tk()
#root.state('zoomed')
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)      # `weight/sum_of_all_row_weights` = 1/2 height
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)      # `weight/sum_of_all_row_weights` = 1/2 height
#root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # `weight/sum_of_all_column_weights` = 1/1 width

# Upper frame 
canv = tk.Frame(root)
canv.grid(column=0, row=0)

plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = plt.cycler(color=["#4C2A85", "#BE96FF", "#957DAD", "#5E366E", "#A98CCC"])
plt.style.use('ggplot')

L = [i for i in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l = ax.fill_between(L, L)
ax.set_title("Upper plot")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, canv)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

# Lower frame 
canv2 = tk.Frame(root)
canv2.grid(column=0, row=1)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
l2 = ax2.fill_between(L, L)
ax2.set_title("Lower plot")
    
canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, canv2)
canvas2.draw()
canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack()

root.mainloop()


EDIT:
And if you need to set specific height
widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
widget['height'] = 300
widget.pack()

widget2 = canvas2.get_tk_widget()
widget2['height'] = 300
widget2.pack()

and it doesn't need to use grid() but it will not resize it when you resize window.
